# Send email using sendgrid through swiftmailer from google cloud

Tags: symfony, email, google-app-engine, swiftmailer, sendgrid

I'm trying to send an email from a cli application using symfony2 with swiftmailer. The application is hosted in google cloud and the email service I'm trying to use is Sendgrid.

When I'm trying to send emails from the local environment it works perfectly but when trying to send if from google cloud machine I keep getting `Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.sendgrid.net [Connection timed out #110]`

I've added ports 2525 and 465 in firewall rules of the cloud machine.

`telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 2525` works perfectly on the machine (and is the only port that works). I've tried all the combinations of sengrid mail ports (465, 2525, 587) and encryption types (tls, ssl) whiteout success.

Does anyone had the same problem before or has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using App Engine standard or App Engine Flexible?  With standard, the client you're using would need to use the sockets API:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/sockets/

If you're using App Engine Flexible, this should "just work":

https://cloud.google.com/php/

We even have a sample here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/sendgrid

If you're stuck on standard, another option here is to use the send grid HTTP API:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/index.html

Hope this helps!